# Change inner HTML based on PHP return

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a simple web page with a form consisting of a text entry box and a button. The onclick event of the button fires a script in the head. The script calls a separate PHP page, and checks the submitted text. If the value is "foo" it should say correct, if it's anything else it should say incorrect.

No matter how I tweak it, I can't get anything to show up in the inner HTML of the div with the id of response_one. I'm working off of the W3Schools tutorial found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp) but just can't seem to make this work. I've included the html / PHP below, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>See</title>
    <script>
    function show(str) {
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "check_one.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainbody">
  <form>
    Answer: <input type="text" name="answers">
    <input type="submit" onclick="show(this.value)">
  </form>
  <div id="response_one"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and check_one.php:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$q = strtolower($q)

$result = ""

if ($q === "foo") {
  $result = "Correct";
} else {
  $result = "Incorrect";
}

echo $result
 ?>
```

Comment: and request are sent? Check browser developer console (network) and if sent then check response. It may be PHP server problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

Multiple problems here:

1. Your button is a submit input. On click, your browser will submit the form. None of your AJAX would matter because the page will refresh before you see any result.
2. Your button does not hold the value. The input field `<input type="text" name="answers">` does. It is a mistake to run `show(this.value)` because you don't really plan to check the submit button's value.
3. There are multiple syntax error in your `check_one.php` file. Please run command line `php -l check_one.php` or use browser to browse `check_one.php?q=foo` to check it.

### Quick Fix

I'll leave the php syntax error to you and focus on your form. Here is how I'm going to fix it:

1. Change the submit button from `<input type="submit">` to `<button type="button">`. This will prevent form submission on click.
2. Alter the `onClick` function to access the value of your text input `answers` instead of `this.value`.

**The Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>See</title>
    <script>
      function show(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = "";
          return;
        } else {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
          };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "check_one.php?q=" + str, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainbody">
      <form>
        Answer:
        <input type="text" name="answers">
        <button type="button" onClick="show(this.form['answers'].value)">Check</button><!-- only this line is changed -->
      </form>
      <div id="response_one"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Once you fixed your `check_one.php`, you'll get your desired result.

### Room for Improvement

There can still be problem with your form. If the user press "Enter" instead of clicking the button, your form will be submitted. So instead of just intercepting the `click` event of the button, you'd be better off **capturing the form's submit event**.

So here are the improvements:

1. Add an [id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) to your form.
2. Use [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to find the form and intercept [the submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).
3. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent form submission.
4. Find the `answers` value and do the `XMLHttpRequest`.

**The Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>See</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainbody">
      <form id="check-form"><!-- added id="check-form" -->
        Answer: <input type="text" name="answers">
        <input type="submit"><!-- removed onClick attribute -->
      </form>
      <div id="response_one"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    // Moved script after body so the form element would exist before
    // this script is run.
    document.getElementById('check-form').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
      var str = evt.target["answers"].value; // get the answers field value

      // The logics previously in your `show()` function
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response_one").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "check_one.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response and the assistance. I'm going to give this a try when I get home from work. Trying to code while caring for a four month old is hard, so the help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @jzakilla: I know how you feel, dude. I've got a 2 years old at home :-)

Comment: Thanks a million again! I fixed the php and made the first set of recommended changes. I'm going to go over your second set of improvements this weekend. Right now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgot some of the ";" at the end of the code. How about

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$q = strtolower($q)

$result = ""

if ($q === "foo") {
  $result = "Correct";
} else {
  $result = "Incorrect";
}

echo $result
 ?>
```

To

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$q = strtolower($q);

$result = "";

if ($q === "foo") {
  $result = "Correct";
} else {
  $result = "Incorrect";
}

echo $result;
 ?>
```